# Wordpress : rename the section url name

Tags: wordpress, html, url, rename

I'm managing a site under Wordpress using a visual page builder to create the page and the content (Unyson plugin).
The main content is on the home page (one page style).

The result is nice but the different pages (different parts on the home page) take the name of the section id on the url bar.

Eg for the contact page: ../#section-79
What i would like : ../contact

[Here is the site](http://www.whow.fr)
>>> Click on the footer links to see the pages names in the url.

1- Can we give a "title" to a section id ? 
Or we have to change the id itself to change the url ?

2- Did not find the file where to change page and section id ?
I should check in the plugin files ? Or the theme files ?

Thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a similar problem. You can change how the path to every WordPress page looks like straight in the WordPress Settings. Here is more detailed information about this process: http://codex.wordpress.org/Permalinks

Hope this helps.